# Fundamental limit in two variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Can I write that  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$$
and, hence, that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=1$? If so, why can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Just use polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos t\;\;,\;\;r\sin t$$

and observe that $\;(x,y)\to (0,0)\iff r\to 0\;$ , so your limit's simply

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\sin r^2}{r^2}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2r\cos r^2}{2r}=1$$

Comment: Who says that x and y have the same radius? The convergence can be of different speed relatively to x and y, so this doesn't hold

Comment: Nobody. I'm just making $\;x,y\;$ approach zero *around* circles with less and less radius each time. After all, they **both** must approach zero so we can assume they both are on a circle of radius $\;r\;$ approaching zero...but I think you've a point about the convergence to zero speed, though I think this shouldn't matter that much. I need to mull on this a little more. Thanks.

Comment: No you can't assume that, it doesn't take into account all the existing possibilities (x,y) can follow to have (x,y)-> (0,0). For instance, y=2*x , which is possible, and maybe (since your proof doesn't take care of this case) the limit is not the  same.
I agree it doesn't matter that much, but I've seeen cases where this was of importance, so I'd rather point it out. I also like circling convergence :)

Comment: That's why I used an inequality, to bring the problem into a one variable by enclosing the couple (x,y) into two circles of different but very small radius :)

Comment: @mvggz What?  Your question doesn't make any sense.  It's not that $x$ and $y$ have the same radius, whatever that means, it's that every point $(x,y)$ can be written in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ with radius $r$ and angle $\theta$.

Comment: Hidden in here is a claim about limits of compositions of functions. The important (unwritten) function here is $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$, or its (partial) inverse. The claim that "you can switch to polar coords" is a claim about limits of compositions, and requires proof.

Comment: @SpanIAm , I see what you mean and I did not express myself correctly but essentially I was trying to say what John said much better. For instance the speed with which x or y converge to 0 can matter sometimes, "whatever that means "

Answer (score 1):

You can say that IF the second limit exists. But it's possible to have similar limits where that substitution is not valid. For instance, 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} sign(x^2) = 1
$$
while
$$
\lim_{u \to 0} sign(u)
$$
does not exist. (Here "Sign" is the function that's $+1$ for positive arguments, $-1$ for negative ones, and $0$ for $0$.)

As for "why can you do it", if you write out the definition of limit in terms of epsilon and delta, you can see that things work out. I think you need to take a square root of delta (or perhaps square delta) somewhere, but ...

More generally, you have

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f \circ g(x) = \lim_{u \to L} f(u) 
$$
where 
$$
L = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)
$$
*provided* all three limits exist. I'm pretty sure that this is proved in Spivak's *Calculus* in some detail, but I don't have my copy here at home with me.

By the way, it's possible for

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f \circ g(x)
$$
to exist even if 
$$
\lim_{u \to L} f (u)
$$
does not. As an example, consider $g(x) = 0$, the constant function, and $f(x) = sign(x)$; and take the limit of $f \circ g(x)$ as $x \to 0$.

The generalization to two variables doesn't introduce any really new complexity here, so understanding the 1-variable case is sufficient. There are, however, other things where the generalization to two variables *does* introduce new complexity, so don't get complacent based on my simple explanation!

Comment: Please, is the Spivak's Calculus volume 1 or 2? @John

Comment: It's the book "Calculus", by Michael Spivak. It's up to the 4th edition at this point, but any edition will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it requires to put yourself sufficiently around 0, to have the monotony of the Sinc function.

Suppose $\;(x,y)\;$ verify :  $\;U \leq$ $x^2 +y^2\leq 2*U\;$

$\;U\;$ is supposed to be very small, and in particular smaller than $\;\frac\pi2\;$.

On $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ , Sinc is decreasing , so :

If you call your two variables function f, you get :

Sinc(2*U) $\leq$ f(x,y) = Sinc( $x^2 +y^2$) $\leq$ Sinc(U)

By definition here, (x,y) -> (0,0) if and only if U->0

hence there is your equivalence, and the limit is 1

Comment: What do you call "sinc" to? Is it $\;\sin\;$ = the sine function, or something else? I think you mean $\;\text{sinc}\, x:=\frac{\sin x}x\;$ . Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I thought the notation was usual, sorry I don't know the custom very well yet :)